# When to use `require`, `load` or `autoload` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module

I understand the subtle differences between `require`, `load` and `autoload` in Ruby, but my question is, how do you know which one to use?

Other than being able to "wrap" a `load` in an anonymous module, `require` seems to be preferred.

But then `autoload` allows you to lazy load files -- which sounds fantastic but I'm not sure practically what you gain over `require`

Is one method preferred over the other? Is there a situation where one method stands out?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Generally, you should use `require`. `load` will re-load the code every time, so if you do it from several modules, you will be doing a lot of extra work. The lazyness of `autoload` sounds nice in theory, but many Ruby modules do things like monkey-patching other classes, which means that the behavior of unrelated parts of your program may depend on whether a given class has been used yet or not.

If you want to make your own automatic reloader that loads your code every time it changes or every time someone hits a URL (for development purposes so you don't have to restart your server every time), then using `load` for that is reasonable.

Comment: See Boris' answer below which contains a link to a more recent discussion regarding autoload. It's still present in 2.1: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-autoload

Comment: No, it's still very much a part of Ruby 2.3.0: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload, but according to the discussion in this bug (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653) the likely target will be Ruby 3.0.

Comment: the autoload link is dead

Comment: So it is normal to have 'load' for development and 'require' for production? With an if else statement?

Comment: @echan00 no, you should use `require` for both development and production. `load` should only be used if you are writing something special like your own reloader; but there are already plenty of good reloaders that already exist for development purposes. Rails includes one, there's one available for Sinatra, etc. If you use `require` in your code, the reloaders will behave correctly.

Comment: As of Feb 2019, Matz has decided to keep `autoload` (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653#note-46).

Answer (score 21):

**mylibrary.rb**

```
puts "I was loaded!"

class MyLibrary
end
```

Try in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'mylibrary'
I was loaded!
=> true

irb(main):001:0> autoload :MyLibrary, 'mylibrary'
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> MyLibrary.new
I was loaded!
=> #<MyLibrary:0x0b1jef>
```

See the difference.

Comment: The question asker knows the difference between require and autoload, he was asking when you should use one rather than the other.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for pointing it out. You are right. As mentioned by user979339 above ..autoload should be used where time is critical and still you want to speed up the process. For example in the application servers like "thin". If you look at the thin source code then you will find out that the author has used autoload instead of require to load thin's core parts like command, connection and logging this speed ups thins initialization.

Comment: You have to be careful about libs that aren't registered with Ruby stdlib and rubygems so require './filename-no ext' as an example for a local lib. Maybe you could fix this in your code and then delete my comment? But thanks for the simple example. But what about 'load'?

Answer (score 15):

here's what you gain with `autoload` over `require`:

`autoload` is primarily for speeding up the initialization phase of your Ruby program or Rails application.  By not loading the resources until they are needed, it can speed up things quite a bit.

Another advantage is that you may not need to load some parts of the code, if the user doesn't use certain features -- thereby improving load time and reducing the memory footprint.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what others have already told you, future of `autoload` is uncertain. It was scheduled to be deprecated in Ruby 2.0, but the deprecation wasn't made in time for the 2.0 feature freeze. It is now expected that `autoload` will be deprecated in Ruby 2.1, [but that is not even certain anymore](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653).

Comment: That feature thread has since been closed with the resolution that `autoload` will not be deprecated. https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653#note-46

Answer (score 0):

Here're the use cases for each method.

1. `load` to pick up any changes you made to a file while the program is running.
2. `autoload` to speed up the initialization of your library by lazily loading the modules.
3. `require` when you want to use external gems.
4. `require_relative` for local files relative to the current working directory.

Source: [Understanding the `load`, `autoload`, `require`, and `require_relative` methods in Ruby](https://www.akshaykhot.com/difference-between-load-autoload-require-in-ruby/)