# What is the difference between require and load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between using:

```
require 'digest'
```

and

```
load 'digest'
```

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170638/how-does-load-differ-from-require-in-ruby/3170650#3170650) clearly explains the difference between require and load.

Comment: The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647219/27358) is more clear, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you `require` the same file twice, it will be loaded and evaluated only once. `load`, on the other hand, loads and evaluates the file every time. There are also differences in how actual filename is resolved ([thanks, Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647240/125816)).

### What does this mean practically?

Let's say we have a library `foo`

```
# foo.rb

class Foo
  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
  
  def quux
    puts 'quux'
  end
end
```

Then we have a file which makes some non-idempotent operations. Say, undefines a method

```
# mod.rb
class Foo
  undef :bar
end
```

Then, if we `require` mod.rb twice, nothing bad happens. `bar` gets successfully undefined.

```
# main.rb
require './foo'

Foo.instance_methods(false) # => [:bar, :quux]

require './mod'
require './mod'

Foo.instance_methods(false) # => [:quux]
```

But if we `load` mod.rb twice, then second `undef` operation will fail, because method is already gone:

```
# main.rb
require './foo'

Foo.instance_methods(false) # => [:bar, :quux]

load 'mod.rb'
load 'mod.rb'

Foo.instance_methods(false) # => 
# ~> mod.rb:2:in `<class:Foo>': undefined method `bar' for class `Foo' (NameError)
# ~>    from mod.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ~>    from -:6:in `load'
# ~>    from -:6:in `<main>'
```

There's no error with `require` because in that case `undef` happens only once. Granted, this example is quite contrived, but I hope it illustrates the point.

Comment: Can you explain this line:- `But if we load mod.rb twice, then second undef operation will fail, because method is already gone` . What exactly do you mean by gone ?

Comment: "gone" means "undefined", "is no more", "does not exist".

Comment: I'm sorry if my previous question wasn't that precise.. I'm trying to understand what exactly happens to the "method bar" as part of the first `load 'mod.rb'` that makes the second `load 'mod.rb'` throw an error saying `undefined method bar` ?

Comment: @boddhisattva: well, it is being undefined. Removed from existence. When we load "mod.rb" second time, it tries to undefine non-existing method. Hence the error.

Comment: In RSpec, why does running "load 'Rakefile`" work but "require 'Rakefile'" does not work?

Comment: Why does this not fail immediately when you try to load it the second time? Why does it fail instead when you call `instance_methods`?

Comment: @Jwan622: you're misinterpreting the output. It fails during second `load`.

Comment: Oh I see, Foo.instance_methods(false) never actually executes.