# what's the easiest way to setup a ruby/rails sandbox locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sandbox

I like to play with dynamic programming languages before I get confident regarding their dynamic behaviors. While there are online ruby sandbox sources available, I  prefer to test it out locally.

In javascript a html file with script tag is sufficient to write any sample javascript code.

What's the equivalent of forming this sandbox for ruby with...?

```
1. a boilerplate
2. manually setting up ruby sandbox (prefered)
```

Comment: Are you talking about installing a ruby environment?  irb ships with most ruby installers I know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a ruby sandbox `$ irb` will do the trick.

If you want a ruby on rails sand box `$ rails c -s` short for `$ rails console ––sandbox`.

> This command loads our Rails application, connects to the database and automatically starts a database transaction. All database operations performed within this console session are rolled back upon leaving the console.

Comment: Why not short for `rails console --sandbox`? :)

Comment: is there a easy way to include(rbfiles)

Comment: Yeah, once in irb you can just `load './filename.rb'` or better yet you can `require './filename.rb'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170638/how-does-load-differ-from-require-in-ruby

Comment: does that answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

Install ruby https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

And use Interactive Ruby Shell(IRB) https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

BitNami is by far the easiest setup for a local installation:
[https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby](http://BitNami%20RubyStack)