# How can I load other scripts into the main script?

Tags: ruby, runtime-error

I have a  script titled ADA.rb. At the beginning of it, it loads some other  scripts into itself:

```
load 'dev_mode.rb'
load 'active_mode.rb'
load 'login.rb'
load 'new_user.rb'
load 'discussion_algorithim.rb'
```

All five of these  scripts are in the same folder as ADA.rb as you can see in the below picture

[image: File Layout]

The problem is, whenever I try and run ADA.rb, I get this error:

[image: Error Message]

It says:

```
C:/users/----/desktop/Project ADA/ADA.rb:1:in `load': cannot load such file -- dev_mode.rb (LoadError)
    from C:/users/----/desktop/Project ADA/ADA.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What might be wrong? I think it's because I moved the containing folder from my old computer to my new one.

I thought it might have been a problem with dev_mode.rb, so I commented out that, but then Ruby returned the same error but referred to the second load instance.

Comment: Check out this SO answer for the difference between `load` and `require`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170638/how-does-load-differ-from-require-in-ruby

Comment: Please post the error message. The image is practically unreadable, at least on my phone.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ok I will. Didn't think about mobile users. Sorry :)

Comment: @JörgWMittag done. I added it.

Comment: Please read http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. It's chockfull of suggestions for how to ask questions.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the suggestion. However, I've already done extensive searches on google and SO, but none of the questions, including the one that you marked this a duplicate of, have provided a solution. This is not a duplicate of that question, as I am not uninformed about the difference between load and require. I've already tried both with their proper syntax, and neither work. This is clearly caused by some other problem; the script used to work fine, and then I did something to one of the loaded scripts, and the whole thing went kaput and wouldn't load any of them. Please unmark it.

Comment: When asking a question, we expect you to tell us what you've tried. That includes where you've searched and why those searches didn't help, and especially applies to questions that are on SO. Without that information we will point to SO answers, other answers on the internet, etc., and the question will be closed. I can't unmark the question, but you can add the missing information to the question and then we can vote to reopen it. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: When developing code it's *really* important to use a revision control system. git and Github are very popular, and are free, and work great. Then you can revert your code to undo the changes. Writing unit tests will help you also as they can test after EVERY change you make so you immediately know if you broke something, not farther down the line.

Comment: @theTinMan that's great if you happen to know git. (I don't)