# Ruby NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby

Just started with Ruby - and already stuck :)

I have a module like this:

```
module Simple
  Env = AppEnv::Environment.new { |env, src|
    env.test = src.test
  }

  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += [
      "#{config.root}/app/lib/"
    ]
  end

end
```

Then a class named `simplex.rb` in the folder /app/lib

```
class Simplex

    def initialize(some)
        puts(some)
    end

end
```

Finally a rake task that looks like:

```
task(:simple => 'simple:default')

namespace(:simple) {

  desc('Run simple, first task')
  task(:default => :load) do
    Simplex.new('okok')
  end
}
```

However I keep getting the error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Simplex`

I would have thought the autoload_paths would allow `Simplex` to be found.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong - seems really trival but I cant see what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your Rake file try adding `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/simplex"` to bring in your `Simplex` class. `Autoload` works like this:

**mylibrary.rb**

```
puts "I was loaded!"

class MyLibrary
end
```

**IRB**

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'mylibrary'
I was loaded!
=> true

irb(main):001:0> autoload :MyLibrary, 'mylibrary'
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> MyLibrary.new
I was loaded!
=> #<MyLibrary:0x0b1jef>
```

I would highly recommend reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804297/when-to-use-require-load-or-autoload-in-ruby) on what the difference between `require` and `autoload` is. More importantly, `autoload` is in the process of being deprecated because of pitfalls regarding it's lazy loading.

Comment: Had to use require like above - well, I used require "./app/lib/simplex"

Comment: Some people place their `lib` folder in rails root, but if yours is in the `app` directory that works too.